# Placement of "tout" as an object in a sentence

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, ordre-des-mots

In the sentence

> Elle a tout fait

Why is "tout" between "a" and "fait"?

Can't it be

> Elle a fait tout

If you want to say "they all have done everything" would you say:

> Elles ont tous tout fait

Or

> Elles ont tous fait tout

Comment: First of all if you use "Elles" as a subject the sentence would be "Elles ont *toutes* tout fait" and not "Elles ont *tous* tout fait". ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Tout** clarifies the meaning of a verb, an adverb or a noun.

- In the case tout is clarifying a verb or an adverb, it is an adverb and is invariant.
- In the case tout is clarifying a noun, it is an adjective and has to be made agree with the noun :

  - tout masculine sing.
  - tous masculine plur.
  - toute feminine sing.
  - toutes feminine plur.

---

### As an adverb specifying an adverb

**Tout** has to precede the word he specifies :

> Elle fait tout **simplement** ...
>   Elle a tout **simplement** fait

Here to specifies the adverb **simplement**

---

### As an adverb specifying a verb

**Tout** has to follow the verb
In the case of a compound tense, tout has to follow the conjugated part

> Elle **fait** tout.
>   Elle **a** tout fait

In both cases, tout specifies the verb **faire**

---

### As an adjective

**Tout** has to precede the determiner :

> Tous **les** jours
>   Tout **le** nouveau quartier
>   Toutes **les** nouvelles fleurs

Comment: You should precise that "Elle fait tout simplement" (in the first case you're explaining) doesn't mean "She does everything simply" in that specific example, but "She quite simply does [something]". Otherwise it would be the second case, an adverb specifying a verb.

And I disagree with the fact that "tout" HAS to follow the verb or the conjugated part (this is the OP question): "Elle a fait tout ce qu'on attendait d'elle". It's the second case, an averb specifying a verb, am I right?

Comment: You are alright on the first part, i should have writen this somewhere, that it is an ambiguous case, and the adverb has here some kind of precedence over the verb.  
But i don't on the last part : tout does not specify the verb, let's go further :  
"Elle a fait tout ce qu'on attendait d'elle"   
Tout precise the object "ce" described by the subordinate "qu'on attendait d'elle".  
"Elle a fait tout ce qu'on attendait d'elle"  
"Elle a donc fait tous ses devoirs"

Comment: In "Elle tout fait" and "Elle a tout fait", "tout" is an indefinite pronoun, not an adverb. "faire" is a transitive adverb and requires a direct object; in this case, "tout". One can easily confirm that by replacing "tout" will a real adverb (eg. bien) and noticing that the sentence remains incomplete: "Elle bien fait". She does what?  Anyway, "tout" indeed behaves like an adverb with regard to its position in the sentence when it is an indefinite pronoun.

Answer (score 1):

"Elle a fait tout" sure sounds strange, but I wouldn't assure it is wrong. I wouldn't say it this way in most cases but that could happen sometimes, especially at speaking. When you put something behind "tout", it becomes mandatory to put "tout" at the end: "Elle a fait tout son possible" (= "She did everything she could").

About "they all have done everything", there is a mistake: "tous" must be "toutes" since it refers to "elles". So like I said, it's mostly "Elles ont toutes tout fait", but I couldn't tell if "Elles ont toutes fait tout" is really wrong.

Comment: Elle a fait* si c'est au passé (mais c'est un détail). Le mieux est de dire "*Elle a tout fait*" si il veut concerner la même structure. Dire "*they all have done everything*" est étrange. Je dirais plutôt "*Ensemble, elles ont tout fait*" qui semble plus correcte. A moins que l'on veuille exprimer un ensemble de tâches effectué individuellement par toutes, et là on dira "*Elle ont toutes tout fait*". L'usage du verbe faire n'est pas le plus approprié de mon point de vue. On lui préférera *compléter*.

Comment: @GautierC Difficile de dire que *fait* n'est pas approprié sans savoir de quoi il s'agit. En tout état de cause, *compléter* a un sens beaucoup plus restreint que *fait* et c'est aussi un faux ami de *to complete* = *terminer/finir/réaliser*.

Comment: @jlliagre pas faux. C'est vrai que *faire* est un verbe passe-partout. Exact aussi concernant compléter.

Comment: @GautierC Merci j'ai corrigé l'oubli de l'auxiliaire dans un des exemples.